# Чат на SignalR ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Как можно написать чат на WebSocket из Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets а не из System.Web.WebSockets. Создал класс, для того, чтобы написать методы OnMessage, OnOpen и т.д:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets;


namespace Drocsid
{
    public class MyWebSocketHandler : WebSocketHandler
    {
        public MyWebSocketHandler(int? maxIncomingMessageSize) : base(maxIncomingMessageSize)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Затем, попытался назначить его обработчиком:

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.WebSockets;

    namespace Drocsid
    {

        public class ChatHandler : IHttpHandler
        {

            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
                    context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new MyWebSocketHandler(1024));
            }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "Drocsid.MyWebSocketHandler" в
>   "System.FuncSystem.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocketContext,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task".

В строке `context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new MyWebSocketHandler(1024));`

Comment: Зачем вам эти извращения?

Comment: @VadimBondaruk делаю видео-бота и постоянно приходится передавать json с данными о видео, а со вторым вариантом вебсокетов это не очень удобно

Comment: Ну так используйте тогда полноценный Signalr

Comment: @VadimBondaruk Hub или Persistent Connection API?

Answer (score 0):

`AcceptWebSocketRequest` ожидает параметром делегат `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>`. Заверните вызов вашего хэндлера в метод:

```
context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(context => 
        new MyWebSocketHandler(1024).ProcessWebSocketRequestAsync(context));
```